RVO & NRVO: How to efficiently return a member of a local object?
#include <vector>

struct A {
    std::vector<int> coll;
};

std::vector<int> f1() {
    A a;
    return std::vector<int>{std::move(a.coll)};
}
    
std::vector<int> f2() {
    A a;
    return std::move(a.coll);
}

Consider f1 and f2 in the code snippets above, which one is preferable?

gcc, clang and cl are giving the exact same assembly, which seems legit. https://godbolt.org/z/z4x513WM5

There is no diffrence between f1 and f2. See cpp insights

f2 seems clearer to me.

There's no NRVO here. The definitive answer is always "stare at the assembly" because at this level of optimization, tiny changes can cause a noticeable performance difference.

@PasserBy • Scream into the void.  Gaze into the abyss.  Stare at the assembly.

"which one is preferable?" - neither. Just return the source vector  as-is and let the compiler work out the best option: std::vector<int> f3() { A a; return a.coll; }

@RemyLebeau, I think return a.coll; is not guaranteed by the C++ standard to MOVE a.coll rather than COPY it. f1 & f2 are both guaranteed to MOVE a.coll, but f3 is not guaranteed.
